# xml string-array to listView not working

Tags: android

```
public class Menu extends Activity {
    String[] categories;    
    ListView lv;
    Cursor cursor;
    Context context;
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        categories = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.Categories_Array);
        lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listViewCategories);  
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, 
                R.layout.activity_main,
                getResources().getStringArray(R.array.Categories_Array));
        lv.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
    ...
}
```

I keep getting an "unfortuneately Bible CYB has stopped working" when I run the app

Comment: You have `activity_main.xml` set to activity as well as you use the same layout in arrayadapter constructor

Comment: also its a crash and you should post the stacktrace form the logcat everytime a crash happens

Answer (score 0):

The problem you have is that you are giving your `ArrayAdapter` a full Activity's layout to inflate. What you want to do is pass it the row's layout it should use for each of the individual rows it should inflate:

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, 
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,     // or other basic row layout
            getResources().getStringArray(R.array.Categories_Array));
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using a array adapter try using a list adapter.. it wud give it a custom layout u designed ..

```
lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listViewCategories);  
ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, 
            /*id for your custom layout for ex: R.layout.activity_main*/,
            getResources().getStringArray(R.array.Categories_Array),/*Here write the id of the text view where u want to display the info.. forex: R.id.tvExample*/);
lv.setListAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: You can have a custom layout with arrayadapter also. Have a custom class extend ArrrayAdapter and override `getView`

Comment: The problem is op uses the same layout set to the activity. You can have arrayadapter also with a `simple_list_item_1.xml` from the android framework. After all its a string to display in each row 1 item in each row

Comment: If u want to do it with array adapter u have to define a class extending array adapter then defining your whole layout u designed in the xml . and then by making instance of that class i cud use a custom layout.. it becomes a very long process. I used to do that a long time ago.. but now i realized this method was quite easy.. and it also easy to implement in json parsing so i personally like that..

Comment: no i din't use a custom adapter and still used arrayadapter. Check my post. i don't see the need for custom adapter in this case

Comment: ok its not actually a custom layout for a row .. Its the activity layout.. yup then ur code wud do the trick.. i thot he was trying to implement another layout for the rows...

Answer (score 0):

You have set the `activity_main.xml` to the activity and use the same in the constructor of `ArrayAdapter`. To display the a single string in each row

Change this

```
 ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, 
            R.layout.activity_main,
            getResources().getStringArray(R.array.Categories_Array));
```

to

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, 
            R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
            categories);
```

where `simple_list_item_1.xml` is the layout from the android framework

http://androidxref.com/4.4.3_r1.1/xref/frameworks/base/core/res/res/layout/simple_list_item_1.xml

And the constructor

> public ArrayAdapter (Context context, int resource, T[] objects)
>
> Added in API level 1 Constructor
>
> Parameters context    The current context. resource   The resource ID for a
>   layout file containing a TextView to use when instantiating views.
>   objects   The objects to represent in the ListView.